# Swift5 Data is Nil when passed, even when it isn't

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have a strange problem in Swift.

It is related to other questions on passing data between view controllers, however the difference here is that this is intended to pass a simple object loaded from a 'didSelectRowAt' method.

I am passing data from a table view controller when the row is selected.  The data is passed as an object and I can print the data and see it in the council BUT when I try to assign values from it, I get the dreaded: 'Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value' error.  Not sure what I am missing here!

From Table View Controller A:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "existingStudentSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! StudentDetailTableViewController

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedStudent = studentsArray?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
```

Received by Table View Controller B:

```
    var selectedStudent: Students? {
        didSet {

            print("DATA RECEIVED: \(String(describing: selectedStudent))")
            print("DATA TYPE: \ (type(of: selectedStudent))")
            firstNameText.text = selectedStudent?.firstName

            }
        }
```

The 'print' statement shows the test data I input and the 'type of' displays the Students class I setup as follows.

```
DATA RECEIVED: Optional(Students {created = 2019-09-24 12:07:23 +0000; name = Anna Altitude; ...(it's all here)
DATA TYPE: Optional<Students>
```

The code fails when I attempt to display the text in a text field in Table View Controller B.  I see in the call stack, the data for selectedStudent is blank.  But how can that be?  The object is populated and accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside `viewDidLoad`

```
firstNameText.text = selectedStudent?.firstName
```

The problem is when `didSet` triggers the `firstNameText` is nil as the vc isn't yet loaded

Comment: remove it from `didSet`